# Getting exception "attempted duplicate class definition" while creating attribute through AttributeByteCodeGenerator

Tags: cqengine

When implementing cqengine in our application, getting exception  "javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.ClassFormatError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition" from method createAttribute of AttributeByteCodeGenerator.

We are using:

```
SQLParser<Order> parser = SQLParser.forPojoWithAttributes(Order.class,AttributeBytecodeGenerator.createAttributes(Order.class,MemberFilters.GETTER_METHODS_ONLY,                AttributeNameProducers.USE_HUMAN_READABLE_NAMES_FOR_GETTERS));
```

Service Class code:

```
public List<Order> getFilteredOrder() {
        List<Order> orders = orderRepository.findAllByOrderByCreateTimeStampAsc();
        IndexedCollection<Order> orderCollection = new ConcurrentIndexedCollection<>();
        ;
        orderCollection.addAll(orders);
        SQLParser<Order> parser = SQLParser.forPojoWithAttributes(Order.class,AttributeBytecodeGenerator.createAttributes(Order.class,MemberFilters.GETTER_METHODS_ONLY, 
                AttributeNameProducers.USE_HUMAN_READABLE_NAMES_FOR_GETTERS));
        String query = "SELECT * FROM test_order WHERE customerId='12345' ORDER BY createTimeStamp ASC";
        ResultSet<Order> resultSet=parser.retrieve(orderCollection, query);
        List<Order> ordersList=resultSet.stream().parallel().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ordersList;
    }
```

My Order Class:

```
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String customerId;

    @Column
    private String type;

    @Column
    private String productId;

    @Column
    private String status;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private long createTimeStamp;

    public static final Attribute<Order, String> custmerId = new SimpleAttribute<Order, String>("customerId") {
        //public String getValue(Order user) { return user.customerId; }

        @Override
        public String getValue(Order arg0, QueryOptions arg1) {
            return arg0.customerId;
        }
 };

    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() {
        createTimeStamp = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public long getCreateTimeStamp() {
        return createTimeStamp;
    }

}
```

Note that it works fine when I call the getFilteredOrder() method first time. Second time when I call the same method, I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create attribute for member: public java.lang.String com.example.demo.model.Order.getId()
    at com.googlecode.cqengine.codegen.AttributeBytecodeGenerator.createAttributes(AttributeBytecodeGenerator.java:162) ~[cqengine-3.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.example.demo.service.OrderService.getFilteredOrder(OrderService.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.OrderController.getOrders(OrderController.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to generate attribute for class com.example.demo.model.Order, type java.lang.String, name 'id'
    at com.googlecode.cqengine.codegen.AttributeBytecodeGenerator.generateSimpleAttribute(AttributeBytecodeGenerator.java:489) ~[cqengine-3.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.googlecode.cqengine.codegen.AttributeBytecodeGenerator.generateSimpleNullableAttributeForGetter(AttributeBytecodeGenerator.java:276) ~[cqengine-3.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.googlecode.cqengine.codegen.AttributeBytecodeGenerator.createAttributes(AttributeBytecodeGenerator.java:154) ~[cqengine-3.4.0.jar:na]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.ClassFormatError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/example/demo/model/Order$$CQEngine_SimpleNullableAttribute_id"
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:271) ~[javassist-3.25.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1232) ~[javassist-3.25.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1384) ~[javassist-3.25.0-GA.jar:na]
    at com.googlecode.cqengine.codegen.AttributeBytecodeGenerator.generateSimpleAttribute(AttributeBytecodeGenerator.java:485) ~[cqengine-3.4.0.jar:na]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/example/demo/model/Order$$CQEngine_SimpleNullableAttribute_id"
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper$Java7.defineClass(DefineClassHelper.java:182) ~[javassist-3.25.0-GA.jar:na]
    at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:260) ~[javassist-3.25.0-GA.jar:na]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the attributes (or the entire parser) only once, and then cache it so that you use the same attributes or parser for all of your requests.

If you are only planning to access the collection using SQL queries, the easiest option is just to cache the entire parser.